# How does running an application on a Vagrant instance through PhpStorm work?

Tags: php, ssh, vagrant, phpstorm

So, I'm ultimately trying to set up breakpoints and code stepping in a PhpStorm run/debug configuration that runs on a Vagrant/VirutalBox instance.  However, the gaps in my understanding about how PhpStorm integrates with Vagrant are impeding me from getting this to work.  What follows is my current theory of how integrating PhpStorm with the Vagrant instance works and some questions I have.  If you could take the time to correct/expand my theory and/or answer the questions that follow, it would be very helpful.

Theory:
PhpStorm can run code in a Vagrant instance and it does so via SSH tunnel.  Access to the VM is required for breakpoints to function because Phpstorm needs to know where the server is in terms of its execution in order to know when to stall.

Q1: I can currently SSH into the VM by clicking "Start SSH session" and selecting the directory containing my VagrantFile.  When I do this, a CLI into the VM opens in the bottom of the IDE.  Do I need to be SSH'ed into the VM in this manner in order for breakpoints to work?

Q2: My Vagrant instance is configured to run the application code on a certain host name via a certain port.  Do I still need to hit "Run" in Phpstorm in order for the code to run in such a way that breakpoints are hit?  If so, should my run/debug config be on the same port or hostname that my Vagrant instance is running on?

Thanks for your input.

Comment: PHPStorm cares about Xdebug not Vagrant. This video is in french which I do not speak but it got me setup https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QcfGyn_jmm8

Comment: did you try this: [PhpStorm Configuring+a+Vagrant+VM+for+Debugging](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Configuring+a+Vagrant+VM+for+Debugging) ? SSH info also [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Using+the+PhpStorm+built-in+SSH+terminal+and+remote+SSH+external+tools) which is also part of that JetBrains guide.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really familiar with the PhpStorm "internal" way to handle Vagrant as I've always done it manually - that is: open up a shell and type `vagrant up && vagrant ssh` to start the machine and SSH into it.

---

Please refer to [Setting up PhpStorm with Vagrant](https://www.pascallandau.com/blog/phpstorm-with-vagrant-using-laravel-homestead-on-windows-10/#configuring-phpstorm-to-use-the-vagrant-box) for a more detailed explanation (took the images from there), but here is the short version:

- your vagrant machine has to be running

  - `vagrant up` in the folder that contains your vagrant file
- the vagrant box has to be configured as "Deployment Configuration" with the correct path mappings (I would strongly advise to got for the SFTP deployment)

  - [image: SFTP Deployment Configuration]
  - [image: Path Mappings]
    <sub>(source: [pascallandau.com](http://www.pascallandau.com/img/phpstorm-with-vagrant-using-laravel-homestead-on-windows-10/phpstorm/vagrant-path-mappings.PNG))</sub>
- you defined a remote PHP interpreter in PhpStorm that uses that deployment configuration
- [image: Choose PHP interpreter]
  <sub>(source: [pascallandau.com](http://www.pascallandau.com/img/phpstorm-with-vagrant-using-laravel-homestead-on-windows-10/phpstorm/select-php-interpreter.PNG))</sub>
- [image: Setup Vagrant PHP interpreter]
  <sub>(source: [pascallandau.com](http://www.pascallandau.com/img/phpstorm-with-vagrant-using-laravel-homestead-on-windows-10/phpstorm/interpreter-vagrant-via-deployment.PNG))</sub>